# ResultSet getFetchSize() doesn't seem to work?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm having trouble with the `getFetchSize()` function.

I simply need to know if the SQL query has returned zero rows.

I've tried this simple statement:

```
if (rs.getFetchSize()==0)
    System.out.println("HEADLINE");
```

where `rs` is of the `ResultSet` type. The above code doesn't seem to work. It always prints the message whether `rs` is empty or not.

I checked the SQL query itself and it correctly returned non-empty result when rows existed.

Any thoughts on how I can determine whether the query has returned 0 rows?
I googled it and couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[ResultSet.getFetchSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) doesn't return the number of results! From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#i1023619):

> Standard JDBC also enables you to specify the number of rows fetched
>   with each database round-trip for a query, and this number is referred
>   to as the fetch size

You can iterate across the result set and if you don't have any entries, then you can determine that you got no results. Why can't you get the result size immediately ? Because the database is returning you a pointer to its results and it's relying on you to iterate through that (going back to the server for each row).

Comment: when I run an sql querry in my sql i always get a MSG "X row(s) returned". isn't there a function in ResultSet that can give me that information?

Comment: @ronnjack No there isn't because that (usually) isn't known in advance, but only after all rows have been retrieved (which happens in your query tool)

Comment: oki, and what if all i need to know is if 0 rows were returned? i have a while loop that moves on result with while(rs.next());. i want to put an if statment after the loop to print a msg if RS was empty. how do u suggest i do that?

Comment: @ronnjack - just loop and if you get nothing then your result set was empty. Or call ResultSet.next() and if that gives you nothing then your set is empty

Comment: thx, i used if (!rs.first()) to check if rs empty and it works like a charm

Comment: @ronnjack If you really need check, then you could do `if (rs.next()) { do { .. } while (rs.next()) } else { .. }` although I think that looks ugly and not directly intuitive.

Comment: @ronnjack using `if (!rs.first())` might result in errors depending on the JDBC Driver and resultset scrollability

Answer (score 4):

The fetch size is the number of rows that should be retrieved from the database in each roundtrip. It has nothing to do with the number of rows returned.

What you should do is call rs.next() - iff your query didn't return any rows it will return false.

Comment: I have a while(rs.next()) loop on the rs results... i want to put an if statment before the while that will check if rs empty. can i do that with rs.next? won't it move forward in the rs so that my loop won't start from the first result?

Comment: Yes it will. You will have to handle that in some way - for example using a do-while loop like @mark-rotteveel suggests. There simply is no way, which is guaranteed to work, of knowing the number of returned rows before actually fetching them.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think another way to do what you are looking for is this:

```
Class.forName("org.exempleDatabase.Driver");
Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:exempleDatabase:/../smartytwiti", "username", "password");
ResultSet resset = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select count(*) from yourTable;");
resset.last();
int resnum = resset.getRow();
if(resnum<1)System.out.println("HEADLINE");
```

That will take the ResultSet, move to the last row of the set, and then give the number of that row in ***resnum***.  Just remember to move back with ***resset.beforeFirst()*** if you are going to iterate through the results with ***resset.next()***.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server You can put it into sql query:

```
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1)
```

like here:

```
select COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) as NUM,ident as ID,employee as EMP from invoice where date between '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2017-01-31 00:00:00.000'
```

And then, you get results like these:

```
NUM, ID,    EMP
4,   28912, JOHN
4,   28913, JOHN
4,   28914, ADAM
4,   28915, PETER
```

And now, before processing all the data, you can read only first col and first cell to get number of records. Object array [invoices] to store results is declared only once, while getting thirst result.

```
Object[][] invoices = null;
Boolean b_inv = false;
[...]
try {
        Statement stmt = db_conn.createStatement();
        boolean results = stmt.execute(sql_query);

        if (results) {
            try (ResultSet rs1 = stmt.getResultSet()) {
                Integer l = 0;

                while (rs1.next()) {
                    if (!b_inv) {
                        invoices = new Object[rs1.getInt(1)][2];
                        b_inv = true;
                    }
                    invoices[l][0] = rs1.getInt(1);
                    invoices[l][1] = rs1.getString(2);
                    l++;
                }
            }
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException | NumberFormatException dbsi1) {}
```

Isn't it good to put counting of records on SQL Server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're looking for using this code:

```
        Class.forName("org.exempleDatabase.Driver");

        Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:exempleDatabase:/../smartytwiti", "username", "password");

        ResultSet resset = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select count(*) from yourTable;");

        resset.next();//set the pointer to the first row(important!)

        if(resset.getInt(1)==0)
            System.out.println("HEADLINE");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier the getFetchSize does not get the number of results..

You can do something like this.
Initialise an integer and increment it..

```
 int count = 0
 while(rs.next()) {
    count++;
 }
```